# how to install breakpoints at every function in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have a project whose working is unknown to me. I have to catch the code behind the front end of the application, which obviously taking a lot of time. So is there any way to install breakpoints at every function/line of the class so that code catching can be easier.

Thanks....

Comment: Why don't you just use the step over button? it iterates your code instruction by instruction

Comment: Most of the code was using reflection and I was new to it, then. Now it seems a silly question to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

To toggle breakpoints in your code, you have to double click in the left margin on the line you want put the breakpoint. To control breakpoint executions, use the "Step Into", "Step Over", and "Step Return" buttons.